# How to color the inside of a Line object in THREEjs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a code that produces a heart with a red line in a dark screen:

```
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-20.0, 20.0, 20.0, -20.0, -2.0, 2.0)
    var vertices = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
        //x and y are from a parametric function of a heart
        let x = 16*Math.pow(Math.sin(i*(Math.PI/180)), 3);
        let y = 13*Math.cos(i*(Math.PI/180)) - 5*Math.cos(2 * i * (Math.PI/180)) - 2*Math.cos(3 * i * (Math.PI/180)) - Math.cos(4 * i * (Math.PI/180));
        vertices.push(new Vector3(x, y, 0));
    }
    
    let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(vertices);
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"red"}); //I actually am using a shader material, but used this for simplification on this example
    var lineStrip = new THREE.Line( geometry, material ); //if I change this from Line to Mesh it doesnt show anything
scene.add( lineStrip ); 
    scene.add(camera);
    renderer.clear()
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

[image: Heart with a red line in a dark screen]

I want to to color the inside of the heart, so it will be a whole red heart, what can I substitute on this code to produce this effect?

Comment: You asked the same question but for a different shape yesterday, and I took the time to write an answer for you. Why did you delete that question and post this one instead?

Comment: @Berthur You suggested I should use Mesh, instead of line, that's why I commented if I used Mesh it wouldn't show anything.
Also, my former question was about a circle, in this it's a heart, and I can't use the same setFromPoints method to draw this heart.

Comment: If you have a set of points (essentially, your heart shape is a polygon) and you want to render the interiour of the polygon, you need to triangulate it, i.e., create triangles that fill the surface. If you don't want to do this yourself in your shape generating code, you can use e.g. this helper: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/Earcut

Comment: You can see how it was done in the [official Shapes example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shapes#webgl_geometry_shapes).

Comment: @Berthur Could you write a little bit of code using this method in this context, please?

Comment: See about ShapeGeometry in the docs.

Comment: @Jonas I suspect that Marquizzo's suggestion is better, however. And you can see how that example was done in the source code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html
If you cannot understand this code, I suggest playing with it and removing some parts until it becomes easier to understand.